# Maven : Get the root path of the parent project in the child project

Tags: java, maven

I have one parent project and many child projects which refer to the parent.
In the parent, I have a profile which executes some security checks. This profile needs a configuration file that I want to have only in the parent project and an output directory that should be in the child project.

**parent pom.xml**

```
<project ...>
    <groupId>com.examle.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>security</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                        <version>${dependency-check-maven.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <failBuildOnCVSS>11</failBuildOnCVSS>
                            <format>ALL</format>
                            <suppressionFile>Parent_Root_Dir/owasp_suppress_false_positives.xml</suppressionFile>
                            <outputDirectory>Child_Root_Dir/owasp_output</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>check</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

**child pom.xml**

```
<project ...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>app-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>app-child1</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Child1</name>

    .
    .
    .

</project>
```

**My Folder Structure looks like**

```
parent-project
    - pom.xml
child1-project
    - pom.xml
child2-project
    - pom.xml
.
.
.
```

My parent is more likely aside than above the child projects.

In the parent pom, I have set the placeholder **Parent_Root_Dir** and **Child_Root_Dir** where I consider to put the variables, but I have no idea which variables to take or if this is even possible.

The security check gets executed in the child project via `mvn clean verify -P security`

I have tried several maven variables like `${maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory}` `${project.basedir}` `${parent.basedir}` but they all refer to the **child root path** when the maven command is executed within the child project.

I also tried to make a custom variable `<main.basedir>` and put that variable instead **Parent_Root_Dir** in the parent pom.
**Child pom.xml adaptation**

```
<properties>
    <main.basedir>${project.parent.basedir}</main.basedir>
</properties>
```

But that also didn't work.

Does anyone know how to get the parent root path? Or has any suggestions on what I can further try? To put the configuration file in every child would be the last option, but I prefer to not doing it because I need this workflow at least for one more profile.

Answer (score -1):

I guess

```
build-helper:rootlocation
```

should do the trick:

https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/rootlocation-mojo.html

Comment: Is your child root not above your parent?

Comment: this always returns the working directory, not the parent